# C++ Try Throw Catch in functions?

Tags: c++, function, try-catch, throw

I am working on this C++ program. I need to use the try throw catch exception handling. My program compiles. However, it is returning `mouse` as not found. When in fact it should be the word `laptop` that should not be found. I have moved the `throw` code from within the `for` loop to outside the `for` loop. but this did not fix the results to be as expected. It seems most logical to have the throw code in the function `getProductID()`, but maybe it is supposed to be in another part of the program?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int getProductID(int ids[], string names[], int numProducts, string target)
{
      for(int i=0; i< numProducts; i++)
      {
              if (names[1] == target)
                  return ids[i];
      }
      throw(target);
}

int main() //Sample code to test the getProductID function
{
 int productIds[] = {4,5,8,10,13};
 string products[] = {"computer", "flash drive","mouse","printer","camera"};

 try
 {
      cout<< getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "mouse")<<endl;
      cout<< getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "camera")<<endl;
      cout<<getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "laptop")<<endl;
 }
 catch(string str)
 {
      cout<<"Error: "<< str<< " product not found."<< endl;
      cout<<"End of program."<<endl;

      return 0;
 }


 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Use `std::find`. It will also magically fix your code. You should also avoid using raw arrays, especially when passing them into functions. `std::array` knows its size and performs just as efficiently.

Comment: Please throw some std::exception - throw std::string is ugly

Comment: Thanks for the tips Dieter. I am new to learning this. Could you give example of throwing std::exception vs throw std:: string ?

Comment: `throw std::runtime_error("Message");`

Answer (score 5):

Replace `1` by `i` to iterate over all items in the array:

```
if (names[1] == target)
          ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also, use C++ standard tools to make your code more effective. It's good to make a struct to store id and its name in an unit:

```
struct Product
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
};
```

Also, you'd better to `throw` exception derived from [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception):

```
struct TargetNotFound : public std::exception
{
    TargetNotFound(const std::string &target) : target(target) {}

    std::string getTarget() const
    {
        return target;
    }

private:
    const std::string target;
};
```

And, you can use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead of your loop:

```
int getProductID(const std::vector<Product> &p, const std::string &target)
{
    auto i = std::find_if(p.begin(), p.end(), [&](const Product &x)
    {
        return x.name==target;
    });

    if (i == p.end())
        throw TargetNotFound(target);
    else
        return i->id;
}
```

Finally, your main can be something like:

```
int main()
{

    std::vector<Product> products
    {
        {4, "computers"},
        {5, "flash drive"},
        {8, "mouse"},
        {10, "printer"},
        {13, "camera"},
    };

    try
    {
        cout<< getProductID(products, "mouse")<<endl;
        cout<< getProductID(products, "camera")<<endl;
        cout<<getProductID(products, "laptop")<<endl;
    }
    catch(const TargetNotFound &ex)
    {
        cout<<"Error: "<< ex.getTarget() << " product not found."<< endl;
        cout<<"End of program."<<endl;
    }
}
```

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72f548beecc07f77)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int getProductID(int ids[], string names[], int numProducts, string target)
{
   for(int i=0; i< numProducts; i++)
   {
          if (names[1] == target)
              `return ids[i];`
   }
  throw(target);
}

int main() //Sample code to test the getProductID function
{
 int productIds[] = {4,5,8,10,13};
 string products[] = {"computer", "flash drive","mouse","printer","camera"};

 try
 {
    cout<< getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "mouse")<<endl;//once exception is     
    //throw by this function call it goes to catch block after that it does not execute      
    //following line
    cout<< getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "camera")<<endl;
    cout<<getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "laptop")<<endl;
 }
catch(string str)
{
     cout<<"Error: "<< str<< " product not found."<< endl;
     cout<<"End of program."<<endl;

     return 0;
}


return 0;

}
```

once exception is throw by following function call it goes to catch block after that it does not execute other line 
`cout<< getProductID(productIds, products, 5, "mouse")<<endl;`